# Sorting Value By Child

Tags: node.js, firebase, npm, firebase-realtime-database

How can i sort some values by there child value? I have this data here:

```
{
  "229016449593769984": { "coins": 196 },
  "286591003794604034": { "coins": 310 },
  "534534453533050240": { "coins": 0 }
  "423424434234234423": { "coins": 0 }
  "786438864582733432": { "coins": 0 }
  "472462364710480242": { "coins": 0 }
  "213123123455343643": { "coins": 0 }
  "351864080354639883": { "coins": 271 },
  "360700960823050240": { "coins": 3 },
  "445035187370328066": { "coins": 289 },
  "655256461101891585": { "coins": 976 }
}
```

But I want it to look like this:

```
{
  "655256461101891585": { "coins": 976 },
  "286591003794604034": { "coins": 310 },
  "445035187370328066": { "coins": 289 },
  "351864080354639883": { "coins": 271 },
  "229016449593769984": { "coins": 196 },
  "360700960823050240": { "coins": 3 }
  "534534453533050240": { "coins": 0 }
  "423424434234234423": { "coins": 0 }
  "786438864582733432": { "coins": 0 }
  "472462364710480242": { "coins": 0 }
  "213123123455343643": { "coins": 0 }
}
```

(Descending/Highest to lowest) I also want it to filter out 10, and can I map this data?

Comment: I don't think js objects are ordered. It'd be more appropriate to use a [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) and insert your data in order.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As khuynh commented, the keys in a JSON object are unordered. But if you're retrieving this data from Firebase, you're probably looking for:

```
ref.orderByChild("coins").once("value").then((snapshot) => {
    snapshot.forEach((child) => {
        console.log(child.key, child.val().coins);
    });
});
```

In here the `ref` variable points to the root of the JSON you shared. It retrieves all child nodes from that location, ordered by the value of their `coins` property. It then uses `DataSnapshot.forEach` to ensure the results are printed in the correct order.

Answer (score 0):

If it is not firebase object or as mentioned in your question, just for converting your object in descending order:

```
 var obj = {
  "229016449593769984": { "coins": 196 },
  "286591003794604034": { "coins": 310 },
  "534534453533050240": { "coins": 0 },
  "423424434234234423": { "coins": 0 },
  "786438864582733432": { "coins": 0 },
  "472462364710480242": { "coins": 0 },
  "213123123455343643": { "coins": 0 },
  "351864080354639883": { "coins": 271 },
  "360700960823050240": { "coins": 3 },
  "445035187370328066": { "coins": 289 },
  "655256461101891585": { "coins": 976 }
};
obj1 = Object.keys(obj)
s = [];
for(var innerObj of obj1) {
    var x = {};
    x['name'] =  innerObj.toString();
    x['coins'] =  obj[innerObj].coins;
    s.push(x);
}
s1 = s.sort((a, b)=>{return b.coins-a.coins})
console.log(s1)
```

S1 is your required result set.